# can't call google place object function in angular view

Tags: angularjs, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to list all google nearby search result using angularjs but i can't use google place function getUrl() which will return url of place photos

here is my code

**Function in angular controller**

```
 $scope.bars = [];
 $scope.hospitals = [];
 $scope.PlaceSearch = function (type){      
        //ClearAllMarkers();
        if(map.getZoom() > 17 ){ map.setZoom(17)}

    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        service.nearbySearch({          
          bounds:bounds,
          type: type,
          rankBy:google.maps.places.RankBy.PROMINENCE,
          //minPriceLevel:2,
        }, function(results, status, pagination){
            if(status == 'ZERO_RESULTS') return FlashMessage('Zero Results for selected place','alert-info');

            if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                console.log(' false in processResults' );
                return;
            }else{

            }

            switch(type){                               
                case 'bar':
                    angular.merge($scope.bars, results);
                    console.log($scope.bars);
                    if(pagination.hasNextPage) pagination.nextPage();
                break;

                case 'Hospitals':
                    angular.merge($scope.hospitals, results);
                    if(pagination.hasNextPage) pagination.nextPage();
                break;
            }
        }); 
}
```

in this function google return a palce list array which have a photos property. Photos is array with list of place photos each object of photos contains `getUrl()` function which return place photo Url. In my view file i am using this approach .

```
<div class="sr-row clearfix" ng-repeat="bar in bars">
<div class="sr-thumb" ng-if="bar.hasOwnProperty('photos')">
    <img src="@{{ bar.photos[0].getUrl() }}" />
</div>
<div class="sr-thumb" ng-if="!bar.hasOwnProperty('photos')">
    <img src="bar.icon" alt="palceholderImgae" />
</div>
<div class="sr-detail">
    <div class="sr-title">
        <h3>@{{ bar.name | limitTo:30 }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sr-middle">
        <p>@{{ bar.vicinity | limitTo:40 }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sr-bottom">                                                         
        @{{ bar.rating }}
    </div>
</div>
```

and this throws an error
**Error: $interpolate:interr
Interpolation Error**

```
Can't interpolate: {{ bar.photos[0].getUrl() }}
TypeError: b is undefined


Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7B%20bar.photos%5B0%5D.getUrl()%20%7D%7D&p1=TypeError%3A%20b%20is%20undefined
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that issue is that the "ng-if" tries to compile and interpolate its sub-DOM anyway (and then removes it from DOM if value is "false"). So because bar.photos may not exists, it may cause issues.

Maybe try to use "ng-src" on your img element and let it interpolate the expression?

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely is related to function call on unexisting object. You can try this (see an example):
https://plnkr.co/edit/z8mappFjJrGwAtvmSB6C?p=preview

```
<img ng-src="@{{ (bar && bar.photos) ? bar.photos[0].getUrl() : '' }}" />
```

Also make sure, your **photos** parameter has **getUrl** method because within this code

```
case 'bar':
    angular.merge($scope.bars, results);
    console.log($scope.bars);
    if (pagination.hasNextPage) pagination.nextPage();
    break;
```

by default you're receiving only json objects array with items like this:

```
"photos": [{
    "height": 270,
    "html_attributions": [],
    "photo_reference": "CnRnAAAAF-LjFR1ZV93eawe1cU_3QNMCNmaGkowY7CnOf-kcNmPhNnPEG9W979jOuJJ1sGr75rhD5hqKzjD8vbMbSsRnq_Ni3ZIGfY6hKWmsOf3qHKJInkm4h55lzvLAXJVc-Rr4kI9O1tmIblblUpg2oqoq8RIQRMQJhFsTr5s9haxQ07EQHxoUO0ICubVFGYfJiMUPor1GnIWb5i8",
    "width": 519
}]
```

So bar in bars won't have such method as getUrl(). Is you're using custom wrapper for photo_reference to change response, please provide it to see full picture.

Answer (score 1):

Photos array has **PlacePhoto** Object, when i inspected PlacePhoto Object from the response, i didn't find getUrl function. I saw raw_reference Object had property fife_url

so i changed the image src interpolation like this **{{bar.photos[0].raw_reference.fife_url}}**

I hope it will solve your problem

Try this code

```html
<div class="sr-row clearfix" ng-repeat="bar in bars">
<div class="sr-thumb" ng-if="bar.hasOwnProperty('photos')">
    <img ng-if="bar.photos" src="{{bar.photos[0].raw_reference.fife_url}}" />
</div>
<div class="sr-thumb" ng-if="!bar.hasOwnProperty('photos')">
    <img src="bar.icon" alt="palceholderImgae" />
</div>
<div class="sr-detail">
    <div class="sr-title">
        <h3>@{{ bar.name | limitTo:30 }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="sr-middle">
        <p>@{{ bar.vicinity | limitTo:40 }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sr-bottom">                                                         
        @{{ bar.rating }}
    </div>
</div>
```